# Google Tag Manager - storing id of a clicked div/button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-tag-manager

Looked for the answer all over, tried reading seperatly but couldn't find an answer..

I have a site, on which Google Tag Manager is implemented, and I need to extract the id of a clicked button (or its parent).

this is my code:

```js
function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
  var editid;
  $('div.uk-button').click(function() {
   editid = $(this).attr('data-id');
}); 
 return editid;
});
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this within a custom javascript variable in GTM ?

Comment: you need to show how your element is placed in HYML. Sometimes click element may return outer container because of css issues, which will not let you to get the id as mention in the upvoted answer by @sdhaus

Comment: {{Click ID}} is the ID of a clicked tag. will it fit your request ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to create the following custom javascript variable:

```
function(){
  return $({{Click Element}}).attr('data-id');
}
```

This will return the data-id attribute for all events (including clicks).

Attach this variable to the relevant event tag, and use click class contains uk-button as the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I guess something is wrong with the site itself, only returns undefined :\

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the outer function and code like below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('div.uk-button').click(function () {
                    var editid;
                    editid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    alert(editid);
                });                    
            });
```

Comment: Since this is in GTM, I'm trying to avoid the 'alert' function.. and when I'm changing it to 'return' - I'm getting undefined.. And of course, thank you for the answer :)

Comment: You can use the variable editid for extracting id. You should not return its value from this event handler.

Comment: I'm afraid that it only returns undefined.. :\

Answer (score 0):

Hey it looks like you may be not be catching the returned value of the document ready callback.

For example, this returns undefined since the return of $(document).ready() callback is not being returned by the containing function:

```
function testfunc() {
$(document).ready(function(){
  var editid = 'this is the return value';
return editid;
});
}
testFunc()
"returns undefined"
```

I'm guessing that you might be trying to set up a custom javascript variable in GTM. You can still use document ready to ensure the elements are present but the returned value needs to be returned by the outer function for it to be passed into the variable.

So your example should work as follows:

```js
function(){
var editid;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.uk-button').click(function() {
      editid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    }); 
  });
return editid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I'm afraid that it returnes undefined, I guess something is blocking the return functions on the site..